# Error while running test file(.t file) in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to write my first test case in perl with the help of Test::Simple module. 
I have saved the file with `.t` extension now when i am trying to run this file on `windows system` then it says `windows can not open this file`.

I had googled about this and what i found is for running this file you should make a new directory with name /t and keep this file to there.

http://perlmeme.org/tutorials/writing_test_harness.html

I have tried this also but still it is not working.

Can any body gives me some tips.

following is my Test cases :

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl -w

    use Test::Simple tests => 2;
    ok( 1 + 1 == 2 );
    ok( 2 + 2 == 5 );
```

Comment: A lot of your answers are in the link you provided. Did you read it?

Comment: Are you trying to launch the file through Explorer? You need to create an association between .t and Perl! While you could do that, it would make more sense to run it from the console so you get a chance to see the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A .t file in Perl is just a Perl script.  The .t is just there to let you know that it's a test script instead of something else.  The file extension and directory structure really doesn't matter, it's there just to help you can keep your environment clean.

To run a Perl script on Windows, from a command line, simply type `perl <script name>`.  Make sure that you have a Perl executable installed on your system as Windows does not come with one by default, and make sure it is in your path.  If the script you want to run is not in your current directory, make sure to specify the path to the script.

Comment: Also if you have the `prove` tool, it will run the test script and interpret the output in a result summary (or not, depending on options).

Answer (score 0):

In the URL you gave it says:

Now because 'dot-T' files are just normal Perl scripts, you can run them as such -

```
perl t/Monger.t
```

Is it a typo in your post, you wrote /t as a directory to keep your test files in - it should be t/, so just a directory relative to where you are. (That's "just" a convention.)